# Add two View to RelativeLayout.BELOW

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I have **RelativeLayout** on all height and it has two **View**:

1) *'mainItem'* is View to fix height;

2) *'listView'* from rubber(or not fix) height;

I want that *'mainItem'* stay on top and *'listView'* was below *'mainView'* and it stretched at all the rest height **RelativeLayout**.

I do so:

```
mainItem = new ItemList(getContext());
mainItem.setId(0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
addView(mainItem, params);


listView = new ListView(getContext());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(BELOW, mainItem.getId());
addView(listView, params);
```

I get *'listView'* stay on top and stretched at all width and height.
A 'mainItem' stay on top too but under *'listView'*. (*'mainView'* not visible)

Please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are adding a view with height match parent prior to your main view, so there won't be any room left on the bottom even if the list doesn't take up the whole space. Try using a linear layout with weights or if you KNOW the list won't take up the whole screen you can try wrap content on its height but this isn't recommended for scrolling views.

Comment: @zgc7009 the problem was to id = 0. Solution to the problem is to change the id for example 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set the id to be 0. Put some other number and see if that works?
If you have a look at the docs for setID() you will see that it says "The identifier should be a positive number". Zero is not a positive number.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)